# Bookshelf classes getting title and genre of book

Tags: python, function, class, init

I'm trying to write a code that adds 'fiction' books to a Bookshelf and then prints the names of the 'fiction' books. This is what I have so far.

```
class Book:

    def __init__(self,title,genre):
        self.title = title 
        self.genre = genre 

    def get_book(self):
        return self.title

class Bookshelf: 
    def __init__(self,title,genre,books):
        self.title = title 
        self.genre = genre 
        self.books = []

    def add_book(self,book):
        self.books.append(books)
        return True 

s1 = Book('Black Roses', 'Fiction')
s2 = Book('Red and Grey', 'Non-fiction')
s3 = Book('Pride and Prejudice','Fiction')


bookshelf = Bookshelf('Fiction')
```

Any help?

Comment: What is the `2` genre?

Comment: Sorry about that was a typo. Edited it out.

Comment: `Bookshelf()` requires 3 arguments: title, genre, and books. You're only giving one argument.

Comment: Why does it take `books` as an argument, but not use it? Is that really needed?

Comment: Is `Fiction` the title or genre of the bookshelf?

Comment: So I want it to add  's1' , 's2' and 's3' in the Bookshelf. And then I need a code that will print out on the 'Fiction' genre books.

Comment: Fiction is the genre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Book:

    def __init__(self,title,genre):
        self.title = title 
        self.genre = genre 

    def get_book(self):
        return self.title

class Bookshelf: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.books = []

    def add_book(self,book):
        self.books.append(book)
        return True 
    def get_book(self, genre):
        res = []
        for book in self.books:
            if book.genre==genre:
                res.append(book.title)
        return res
    
s1 = Book('Black Roses', 'Fiction')
s2 = Book('Red and Grey', 'Non-fiction')
s3 = Book('Pride and Prejudice','Fiction')


z = Bookshelf()

z.add_book(s1)
z.add_book(s2)
z.add_book(s3)

z.get_book('Fiction')
```

output

```
 ['Black Roses', 'Pride and Prejudice']
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the `Bookshelf.__init__` method initializes `self.books` to an empty list, there's no need for the `books` parameter.

Since each bookshelf is devoted to a specific genre, you should make sure that books are not put on the wrong shelf.

```
class Bookshelf: 
    def __init__(self,title,genre):
        self.title = title 
        self.genre = genre 
        self.books = []

    def add_book(self,book):
        if self.genre != book.genre:
            raise ValueError(r"Can't put a {book.genre} book on a {self.genre} shelf")
        self.books.append(books)

s1 = Book('Black Roses', 'Fiction')
s2 = Book('Red and Grey', 'Non-fiction')
s3 = Book('Pride and Prejudice','Fiction')

f = Bookshelf("Fiction Books", "Fiction")
nf = Bookshelf("Non-Fiction Books", "Non-fiction")

f.add_book(s1)
nf.add_book(s2)
f.add_book(s3)

# Print all fiction books
for book in f.books:
    print(book.get_book())
```